# Wordpress issue with category-slug class

Tags: css, wordpress

I have added a title color for each category that is displayed on the posts. [This is how I want it to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmhWa.png) and [this is the way it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN8Fe.png)

It works fine for one category page https://everythingstudent.co.uk/category/discounts/, but on the others it doesn't https://everythingstudent.co.uk/category/sponsored/ - The section after In case you missed it.

I don't understand why it doesn't respect the CSS assigned. It bugs me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please supply the code you have tried already that covers your problem. You will nbo more likely to get help if you do that (and less down-votes too) Take a moment to visit SO Help Center and the guidelines on how to produce a 'Minimal, Reproducible Example' of your code >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made small mistake. just replace your css with below css. same class in body and article tag so we need to add article tag with class name so it does not conflict with body tag :)

```
article.category-discounts .category_es_title {
    background-color: #0072bc!important;
}

article.category-anothercat .category_es_title {
    background-color: #f8ac87!important;
}

article.category-jackiscool .category_es_title {
    background-color: #75d3f6!important;
}

article.category-sponsored .category_es_title {
    background-color: #00a651!important;
}

article.category-student-life .category_es_title {
     background-color: #ff1744!important;
}
```

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Where is your CSS typed? did you do it manually or through a front-end editor?
In my experience, a lot of times it's something as simple as a theme compatibility issue so you may have to go directly into the source code for the theme itself. 
Let me know some details & I should be able to elaborate more

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but the issue was solved, the classes were wrong assigned.